# MSDTC Error - Call to RpcMgmtInqServerPrincName failed. The partner does not support secure calls

Tags: sql-server, distributed-transactions, msdtc

I'm trying to get MSDTC and SQL Server to work together on Windows 10 Pro. I started the Distributed Transaction Coordinator service and it is using the Network Service account. Whenever I begin a distributed transaction in SQL Server I get the following error:

```
Msg 8501, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
MSDTC on server 'DESKTOP-99PFPB8' is unavailable.
```

I enabled DTC connection manager tracing by following the instructions in this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/926099/how-to-enable-diagnostic-tracing-for-ms-dtc-on-a-windows-based-compute). The trace shows the following:

```
05-11-2018 10:52:25:672 : [3d58.77ac] 0x00000000 [    TRACE_CM] [  TRACE_INFO] InitRpcSecurity (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrrpc.cpp@382): Calling RpcServerRegisterAuthInfo with NT Service\MSSQLSERVER as SPN
05-11-2018 10:52:25:678 : [3d58.75c4] 0x800706d3 [    TRACE_CM] [ TRACE_ERROR] CRpcIOManagerClient::SetRpcSecurity (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrclt.cpp@569): [Remote:DESKTOP-99PFPB8 a2e530a1] Call to RpcMgmtInqServerPrincName failed.  The partner does not support secure calls
05-11-2018 10:52:25:681 : [3d58.75c4] 0x80070006 [    TRACE_CM] [ TRACE_ERROR] CRpcIOManagerClient::PokeWrapper (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrclt.cpp@1174): [Remote:DESKTOP-99PFPB8 a2e530a1] Exception raised in the rpc call C_PokeW
05-11-2018 10:52:25:685 : [3d58.75c4] 0x80000171 [    TRACE_CM] [ TRACE_ERROR] CRpcIOManagerClient::Poke (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrclt.cpp@992): [Remote:DESKTOP-99PFPB8 a2e530a1] SecurePokeWrapper call failed
05-11-2018 10:52:25:688 : [3d58.75c4] 0x00000000 [    TRACE_CM] [  TRACE_INFO] CRpcIOManagerClient::Poke (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrclt.cpp@1035): Secure Poke failed for LRPC and falling back to unsecure mode... Setting RPC security again!
05-11-2018 10:52:25:692 : [3d58.75c4] 0x80070006 [    TRACE_CM] [ TRACE_ERROR] CRpcIOManagerClient::PokeWrapper (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrclt.cpp@1174): [Remote:DESKTOP-99PFPB8 a2e530a1] Exception raised in the rpc call C_PokeW
05-11-2018 10:52:25:694 : [3d58.75c4] 0x80000171 [    TRACE_CM] [ TRACE_ERROR] CRpcIOManagerClient::Poke (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrclt.cpp@1081): [Remote:DESKTOP-99PFPB8 a2e530a1] PokeWrapper call failed
```

I'm stuck at this point. Does anyone know what these errors mean?

Steps I tried:

1. Restarted the DTC service followed by the SQL Server service
2. Reinstalled DTC (msdtc -uninstall, reboot, msdtc -install, msdtc -resetlog)
3. Enabled Network DTC Access (even though this is a single-machine environment). I checked "Allow Remove Clients", "Allow Remote Administration", "Allow Inbound", "Allow Outbound", and "No Authentication Required".
4. Fresh install of Windows!

Answer (score -1):

There are just one computer involved in transaction?

How you are are testing the distributed transaction? 
If you issue just a "begin distributed transaction", this error is throwed?

Also, try use sys internals process monitor, and filters "msdtc.exe" to see if error occurs accessing some windows resource, like files or registry